# CI upload error, You did not select a file to upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have been working in this application for a while, but i never got this error before.
I have been trying to do multiple things to get the solution like modify the post_max_size in the php.ini to 9999M but didn't work, so i don't know where is the error or what i need to do.

```
            $nextId = uniqid();
            $config['file_name'] = $nextId;
            $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
            $config['upload_path'] = '/uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
            print_r($_FILES);
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload() ) {
                $data['msg'] = '     Foto '.$this->upload->display_errors();
                $this->data['contenido'] = $this->load->view($this->mainView.'/nuevo_view', $data, TRUE);
                $this->load->view('templates/main_template', $this->data);
                return;
            } else {
                echo 'success'; }
```

this is the form:

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo $this->router->class.'/nuevo'; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Imagen</label>
        <input type="file" id="imagen" name="imagen" required>
        <span class="help-block m-b-none">480px Ancho por 230px Alto (Recomendado)</span>
    </div>
```

so like the code shows i print the $_FILE to know if its something in the array; this is the output:

```
Array ( [imagen] => Array ( [name] => dropdown.9.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/php7WJQok [error] => 0 [size] => 1182 ) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The do_upload function is looking for a field, called "userfile", unless you change it...

Try this, and see if it works;

```
$this->upload->do_upload('imagen')
```

Comment: No worries. Having the user guide bookmarked always helps me. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Link for [file uploader](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) class of CI

As mentioned **do_upload()** function expects the default file input field to be **userfile**

Either edit the file input field to **userfile**, or use,

```
$this->upload->do_upload('imagen')
```